# Truffle test won't return token name

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, react, test

I have been stuck on this part of my Bootcamp for two weeks now pouring over github and asked on stackoverflow. I have googled my error and found nothing as well as deleting my dependencies and reinstalling them with npm install. I have looked through my provided code and can not find why my test won't return token name any help would be greatly appreciated.

My test is:

```
const Token - artifacts.require('./Token')

 require('chai')
   .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
   .should()

contract('Token',(accounts) => {

  describe('deployment', () => {
    it('tracks the name', async () => {
     const token - await Token.new()
     const result - await token.name()
     result.should.equal('Nemo')
    })
  })
})
```

My return on terminal is.

```
**$ truffle test
**Using network 'development'.
Compiling your contracts...****
===========================
> Compiling ./src/contracts/Token.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test--275-YrpVlDWvY1Vr
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang
SyntaxError: /mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/test/.babelrc: Error while parsing JSON - Bad number at line 1 column 3 of the JSON5 data. Still to read: "babelrc\r\n{\r\n\"presets"
    at error (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:56:25)
    at number (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:212:17)
    at value (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:491:20)
    at Object.parse (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/json5/lib/json5.js:508:18)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.addConfig (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:150:65)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.findConfigs (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:96:16)
    at buildConfigChain (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:61:13)
    at OptionManager.init (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:354:58)
    at compile (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
    at loader (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/mnt/c/pr0/blockchain-developer-bootcamp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at /home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:417:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:414:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:1015:10)
    at /home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:156:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (/home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:155:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/test/run.js:115:1)
    at runCommand (/home/nemo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.5.31 (core: 5.5.31)
Node v14.16.0
```

If you have any advice where to look to solve it would be a great help. Thank you for looking.

Comment: It says about any bad number in the json file check that out.

Comment: r u using webpack or create-react-app